# rtabmap map data (get_map)

Tags: slam, navigation, 3dmapping, rtabmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problem in loading the generated map using RTAB map, I already used rtabmap/get_map service but I don't know how to proceed and export the ply mesh using the command line or rviz. I want  to do that using the command line since rtabmapviz crashes when I load the cloud and then export the mesh since my map is really too big.

when I call get_map service in command line, I get a lot of information displayed (I loaded them to a file), snap shots of this information is available in the following link : [images link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7nb0dtha87o2zhk/AACzfkR7aym6iMC_rmK5W2dya?dl=0)

could this information be used to generate a mesh file (.ply), or is there another way other than rtabmapviz to generate a mesh file ??

Note: I use ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo and I preformed the mapping using rtabmap-ros package and writing a launch file to setup rtab to my robot.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228834/rtabmap-map-data-(get_map)/) by [Randa](https://answers.ros.org/users/23589/randa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The [rtabmap_ros/GetMap](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rtabmap_ros/html/srv/GetMap.html) service returns map data as a graph, not a point cloud. You can however subscribe to `/rtabmap/cloud_map` topic (which is a [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)) to get the point cloud. With [pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros), you can save to PCD format (and convert to PLY):

```
 rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/rtabmap/cloud_map
 pcl_pcd2ply input.pcd output.ply
```

If you connect after mapping, call the service [rtabmap_ros/PublishMap](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rtabmap_ros/html/srv/PublishMap.html) so that rtabmap will regenerate the map's cloud and send it back on the `cloud_map` topic. Parameters for cloud generation by [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) can be found on the ROS wiki with prefix `cloud_` (e.g., `cloud_voxel_size`).

Note that in `rtabmapviz` you can decrease the resolution of the point clouds (increase voxel size) to save memory when exporting.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Randa](https://answers.ros.org/users/23589/randa/) on 2016-03-20**:
Thanks for your suggestion,
I already tried to subscribe to cloud_map and publish the cloud but nothing happened.. as if the cloud_map is empty although I can see the reconstructed map. maybe because the map is so big, I'll try to decrease the resolution and increase voxel size.